# Column mapping option argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have to insert parquet file data into redshift table. Number of columns in parquet might be less when compared to redshift table. I have used the below command.

```
COPY table_name
FROM s3_path
ACCESS_KEY_ID ...
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ...
FORMAT AS PARQUET
```

But getting the below issue when I run the COPY command.

`Column mapping option argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY`

I tried to use the column mapping like

```
COPY table_name(column1, column2..)
FROM s3_path
ACCESS_KEY_ID ...
SECRET_ACCESS_KEY ...
```

But am getting `Delimiter not found` issue. If I specify `FORMAT AS PARQUET` in the above COPY command (which has column list) then am getting `Column mapping option argument is not supported for PARQUET based COPY`.

Could you please let me know how to resolve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns in the parquet file MUST match the table's columns [reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-usage_notes-copy-from-columnar.html) . You can't use column mapping with parquet files.
What you can do: create a staging table and copy parquet file content to it. Then run a insert to your final table using `insert into final_table (select col1, col2 from stg_table)`